# can't get button value on click. I'm getting is null error on my machine but it works fine here and on code pen

Tags: javascript

I'm getting is null error on my machine but when i run this code here or code pen it's working fine

```js
function output() {
  console.log(rock.value);
}

const rock = document.getElementById('rockbtn');
rock.addEventListener('click', output, true);
```

```html
<button id="rockbtn" value="rock">Rock</button>
```

Comment: If your JavaScript code runs before the DOM is constructed, your code won't work. What matters is how the code is included in the HTML.

Comment: Show your HTML!

Comment: You have to add `defer` attribute or move `script` tag to the end of the body

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now, i forgot to put defer in script